# Bottom bracket tool for Shimano BB-R60 Ultegra 6800/105 5800 Hollowtech ii?

Tags: road-bike

I need a bottom bracket tool to fit a torque wrench (I think they are all 3/8" drive as standard).  Wiggle sent me one but it doesn't fit.  Do you know the correct torque wrench tool for this Shimano BB-R60 Ultegra 6800/105 5800 Hollowtech ii ? :

http://www.wiggle.co.uk/shimano-bb-r60-ultegra-6800105-5800-hollowtech-ii/

I got this Lezyne one but its too big :

http://www.wiggle.co.uk/lezyne-external-bottom-bracket-socket-tool/

Shimano supply a plastic TL-FC25 with the BB-R60  B.B but it doesn't fit the Lezyne B.B socket tool.

Park Tool have 3 B.B tools but I don't know which one.  Or where I can get a cheaper one if they are expensive :

http://www.parktool.com/product/bottom-bracket-tool-bbt-49?category=Crank%20&%20Bottom%20Bracket

http://www.parktool.com/product/bottom-bracket-tool-bbt-59?category=Crank%20&%20Bottom%20Bracket

http://www.parktool.com/product/bottom-bracket-tool-bbt-69?category=Crank%20&%20Bottom%20Bracket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Park BBT-59 is the main one you'll see. (If you scroll down a little on your link to it, you'll see it says it's the one for BBR60.) A [less expensive one from Lifu/Icetoolz](http://www.icetoolz.com/ec99/ushop10074/GoodsDescr.asp?category_id=60&parent_id=50&prod_id=M093) now exists and I see it can be found on ebay if you search for "icetoolz m093." It's 1/2in drive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the cheaper icetoolz m093 !!